# Teardrop including icon in Mapbox-gl

Tags: icons, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

In my JS code I would like to create a teardrop marker and add an icon to it using addLayer when adding a tileset, varying the icon depending on some property values.

When adding a layer there is an icon-image setting under layout options to select an icon. With that I can select the maki teardrop marker-15 or I can select one of the other maki icons that are currently supported.

What I would like to do it put other icons on top of the teardrop and colour the teardrop, for the classic icon-on-top-of-teardrop marker.

I also find that icon-color in the paint options for this maki teardrop does nothing - it comes out black every time.

```
const layerDefinition = {
    'id': layer.id,
    'type': 'symbol',
    'source': layer.name,
    'source-layer': layer.name,
    'layout': {
      'icon-image':  'marker-15' ,
      'icon-size': 1
    },
    'paint': {
      'icon-color': "red"
    }
  }

map.addLayer(layerDefinition, insertLayerId)
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to build the SVG icon for each color/icon combination.

The [Maki icon editor](https://labs.mapbox.com/maki-icons/editor/) can do this for you, but only supports a square or circle background, not a teardrop background.

[Makiwich](https://github.com/mapbox/makiwich) is another option, but requires some coding to help generate these teardrop icons with arbitrary icon and color.

You can then either use these generate icons as a [Marker](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#marker) or as a [symbol icon](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#symbol).

`icon-color` can only be used with SDF icons (see https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#addimage, you must pass `{ sdf: true }` as the option to `addImage`, not SVG icons. Some discussion about supporting `icon-color` for SVG based icons is at https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/3605. Multiple icons as part of the symbol icon (so you can have a teardrop background an another icon inside it) is discussed at https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/4366.

Comment: Gave it a go and learned you are only allowed 1000 variations, so doesn't fit my use case. I want to enable data driven icons on tileset data where any combo of maki icon (or font-awesome font) and colour can be combined, with a teardrop or at worst circle background. Another sticking point also seems to be that mapbox expressions can't incorporate calls to js functions, so limited in the way can interpret data - for example our existing data will have a font-awesome tag such as fa-home to indicate which icon but addLayer properties requires a mapbox expression that delivers a character code.